# Why I always get the message "You cannot dump a container with parameters" in symfony console?

Tags: symfony, console, rabbitmq

In Terminal when I try to run my created command I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]]

You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to other   services (reference to service "old_sound_rabbit_mq.split_file_producer" found in "/rabbit").
```

This is what happens when I run my newly created console command:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('split_file')->process();
```

I don't know why it says that `You cannot dump`! I don't dump anything in the project.

Is there something I'm unaware of?

**EDIT**
A part of my services.yml:

```
 <parameters>
        <parameter key="file_path">/var/www/path/file.xml</parameter>
        <parameter key="rabbit" type="service" id="old_sound_rabbit_mq.split_file_producer" />
 </parameters>

<service id="split_file" class="Acme\DemoBundle\SplitFile">
            <argument>%file_path%</argument>
            <argument>%rabbit%</argument>
</service>
```

And this is my console command class:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ReadFileCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('reader:read-file');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->getContainer()->get('split_file')->process();
    }
}
```

Comment: When caching, the container is dumped.

Comment: What do you mean @WouterJ??

Comment: Update your question with the service definition of split_file.  Also, confirm that just running app/console triggers the same error.  Might also try the ever popular clearing of the cache.

Comment: @Cerad, I've updated my question. Please take a look

Comment: @phpGeek I was responding to //I don't dump anything in the project. Is there something I'm unaware of?// Symfony2 caches the router and container in `/app/cache`. In order to do that, the container is dumped.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters only have a key value.  You can't add service etc to a parameter.

```
<service id="split_file" class="Acme\DemoBundle\SplitFile">
        <argument>%file_path%</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="old_sound_rabbit_mq.split_file_producer"/>
</service>
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

1. I'd suggest switching to yml as it's less verbose
2. You could create an alias for old rabbit if you wanted.

Comment: Xml is more powerfull and can be validated using XML schema. There is really nothing wrong with using it

Comment: Within the context of defining a symfony service, how exactly is xml more 'powerful" then yaml?  Within the context of this particular question, explain how the 'possibility' of validating actually helped since validating was not done?  Finally, had he tried to define a parameter with a key using yaml, the error message would have been about a non-existent parameter instead of this dumping stuff.

Comment: What would be the correct way to write RabbitMQ in XML context? For the time being I don't want to spend some more time on other things. thanks.